# Align the drop-down list content under the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

[image]

Above is the result I want, each drop-down list is under the main title.

For example:

- A1, A2, A3, A4 is under A when I click the expand collapse button.
- B1, B2, B3, B4 is under B when I click the second expand collapse button.

But now my drop-down list is not aligned accordingly. You can check my code for more details. Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice.

```js
$(".es_epdtitle").click(function() {
 $('.es_expandct').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
 $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});
 
$(".es_epdtitle1").click(function() {
 $('.es_expandct1').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
 $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});
 
$(".es_epdtitle2").click(function() {
 $('.es_expandct2').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
 $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding: 0; } 
.eservices_left ul li{display:inline;}
.es_expandct, .es_expandct1, .es_expandct2 {
 display: none;
 position:absolute;
 padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
 
.es_epdtitle, .es_epdtitle1, .es_epdtitle2{
  background:url('https://image.ibb.co/jUyN5Q/arrow_up_grey.png') no-repeat;
 width: 30%;
 float:left;
 background-position:right 0px;
 cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
 
.collapsed .es_epdtitle, .collapsed .es_epdtitle1, .collapsed .es_epdtitle2{
 background-image:url('https://image.ibb.co/d669kQ/arrow_down_grey.png');
 width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed">
    <div class="text_maroon_16_bold es_epdtitle">A</div>
    <ul class="es_expandct">
      <li>A1</li>
      <li>A2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed">
    <div class="text_maroon_16_bold es_epdtitle1">B</div>
    <ul class="es_expandct1">
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>B2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed noborder">
    <div class="text_maroon_16_bold es_epdtitle2">C</div>
    <ul class="es_expandct2">
      <li>C1</li>
      <li>C2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to parent to make the drop-down position according to it and move float and width from **text_maroon_16.**. to the parent **mobexpand** to maintain the width and the style

**See code snippet:**

```js
$(".es_epdtitle").click(function() {
  $('.es_expandct').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$(".es_epdtitle1").click(function() {
  $('.es_expandct1').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$(".es_epdtitle2").click(function() {
  $('.es_expandct2').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.eservices_left ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.es_expandct,
.es_expandct1,
.es_expandct2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.es_epdtitle,
.es_epdtitle1,
.es_epdtitle2 {
  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/jUyN5Q/arrow_up_grey.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: right 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.collapsed .es_epdtitle,
.collapsed .es_epdtitle1,
.collapsed .es_epdtitle2 {
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/d669kQ/arrow_down_grey.png');
}

.mobexpand {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed">
    <div class="text_maroon_16_bold es_epdtitle">A</div>
    <ul class="es_expandct">
      <li>A1</li>
      <li>A2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed">
    <div class="text_maroon_16_bold es_epdtitle1">B</div>
    <ul class="es_expandct1">
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>B2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed noborder">
    <div class="text_maroon_16_bold es_epdtitle2">C</div>
    <ul class="es_expandct2">
      <li>C1</li>
      <li>C2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You could always use `flex`:

```js
$(".es_epdtitle").click(function() {
  $('.es_expandct').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$(".es_epdtitle1").click(function() {
  $('.es_expandct1').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$(".es_epdtitle2").click(function() {
  $('.es_expandct2').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.eservices_left ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.es_expandct,
.es_expandct1,
.es_expandct2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
}

.es_epdtitle,
.es_epdtitle1,
.es_epdtitle2 {
  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/jUyN5Q/arrow_up_grey.png') no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: right center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

.collapsed .es_epdtitle,
.collapsed .es_epdtitle1,
.collapsed .es_epdtitle2 {
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/d669kQ/arrow_down_grey.png');
}

.main-ul {
  display: flex;
}

.mobexpand {
 padding: 10px;
 flex: 1 0 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-ul">
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed">
    <div class="text_maroon_16_bold es_epdtitle">A</div>
    <ul class="es_expandct">
      <li>A1</li>
      <li>A2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed">
    <div class="text_maroon_16_bold es_epdtitle1">B</div>
    <ul class="es_expandct1">
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>B2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed noborder">
    <div class="text_maroon_16_bold es_epdtitle2">C</div>
    <ul class="es_expandct2">
      <li>C1</li>
      <li>C2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think may be position relative is the best answer :) Because flex might not works on some browser.